# Is there a simple command for outputting a tab delimited columns?

Tags: python, fasta, assembly, file-formats

I am working on a fasta file and am writing my command in nano within command-line and executing using python, also within a command line.

My objective is to get my command to provide me with a tab delimited file with three columns: first column should contain my **sequence name**, second column should provide me with my **sequence length**, and the third column should show the **sequence itself**.

I have written the following command so far within nano:

For example, I would like my command to provide me with the desired output and with the following order: Gene name ; Gene length ; Gene seq

```
A06842X 45 GORHQRIHQEERHEUWOHRPPTRWFAWWEAKJNFWEJQEFQEPRT

Jb4329PC 21 LDHKQAJTYOWEPLKFREEQW
```

Comment: Hi @KamilSJaron, I appreciate the help! The reason why I am doing this is because it makes it easier for me to easily detect which genes I could disregard if they are over  a certain length. For the command below, I tried it, but I received a "TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, Seq found". I tried googling this but was not able to find anything.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to convert the `Seq` class to `str` class before creating the line, see the edit, it should work now. Regarding the utility of such table, I guess I would always get the gene length on the fly (every time you have the sequence of a gene is really easy to get the length too in any language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what do you want to do with fasta files reformatted like this, but I think something like this should do the job (untested):

```
from Bio import SeqIO 
import sys 

for olig_fasta in SeqIO.parse(sys.argv[1], "fasta"):

  name = olig_fasta.name
  seq = str(olig_fasta.seq)
  seq_len = str(len(olig_fasta.seq))

  print("\t".join([name, seq_len, seq]))
```

Comment: Based on OP's desired order, it should be `print("\t".join([name, str(seq_len), seq])`.

Comment: Yeah, you can prin `Seq`, but to manipulate it as a string one needs to convert it to string using `str` command (I edited the answer, now it should work)